# How to avoid permissions problems with node and nginx directory structure?

Tags: node.js, git, nginx, directory-structure

On my production server I'm successfully using nginx to host a static site and as a reverse proxy for a node app. Currently, the node app is in `/home/myUserName/apps` and the site is in `/var/www/siteDomain.com/html`.

On my local/development machine, the html directory is inside my apps directory (../apps/html). I want to have the same directory structure in production, so that I can clone my git repository and then just run `npm install` in case the package.json has changed (node_modules is in .gitignore).

I get permissions problems when using git and npm in `/var/www/siteDomain.com` because the owner is root and `siteDomain.com` is drwxr-xr-x. I can clone my repo using sudo git, but then all the subdirectories (including html) are owned by root which causes problems (would have to use sudo npm, which I read can make more problems, cannot manipulate files in ftp...).

The other way I could do it is clone the repo to `/home/myUserName/apps`, where everything is owned by my non-root user, and then change the nginx config file to point to `/home/myUserName/apps/html` as the root for the static site.

What is the best way to structure my directories so that I don't have permissions problems when using git and npm? Is pointing the html root to something outside of `/var/www` unusual or will it problems in the future?

P.S. my local machine is Windows, I'm not very experienced with linux (which is running on production server)

Answer (score 1):

You can create projects directory in `/home/username/projectname`

Run `nginx` without root permissions like described below.

Add/Change the following in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user nginx;
```

You should create the user and grant permissions on the webroot directories recursively.

This way only master process runs as root. Because: Only root processes can listen to ports below `1024`. A webserver typically runs at port `80` and/or `443`. That means it needs to be started as root.

To run master process as non root user:

Change the ownership of the following:

```
    error_log
    access_log
    pid
    client_body_temp_path
    fastcgi_temp_path
    proxy_temp_path
    scgi_temp_path
    uwsgi_temp_path
```

Change the listen directives to ports above `1024`, log in as desired user and run nginx by `nginx -c /path/to/nginx.conf`.

And your `node` directory must be placed in `/home/username/projectname`.
Add `node` user, `nginx` user and `git` user to the common group and check projects permissions.